# R: How can I fix my for-loop so it multiplies every element of a row with the corresponding element of a column?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a matrix beta with `nrow=10` and `ncol=10` and a second matrix data with `nrow=10` and `ncol=10`. I want to multiply the columns from beta with the rows from data for ever element.

I already tried to write a for loop:

```
solution1 <- matrix(NA,10,10)

for(i in 1:nrow(data)){solution <- matrix(beta*data[i,])}
```

but this jut shows me a list of 10 times "NA"

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I actually expect a matrix with `nrow=10` and `ncol=10`. Maybe someone has an idea and can help?

Answer (score 0):

The operation of multiplying each element of a row of a matrix with the corresponding element of a column of another matrix is the same as the matrix multiplication defined in linear algebra.

R has a matrix multiplication operator `%*%`

```
solution <- beta %*% data
```

After reading your clarification I found the following simple solution. Multiplying all values element-wise and then taking the transpose of the matrix.

```
solution <- t(beta*data)
```

Which outputs the following results

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    9
[2,]   16   25   36
[3,]   49   64   81
```